# WPF TreeView restores its focus after double click

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a WPF TreeView with XAML shown below:

```
<TreeView x:Name="twElements">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <v8r:IconTypeConverter x:Key="IconConverter"/>
            </TreeView.Resources>

            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="twElements_MouseDoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

The task is to open some form after double click on a child item.

code-behind for DoubleClick event:

```
private void twElements_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is TreeViewItem && ((TreeViewItem)e.Source).IsSelected)
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                var twi = (TreeViewItem)e.Source;

                var Editable = twi.Header as IEditable;
                if (Editable != null)
                {

                    Window Editor = Editable.GetEditor();
                    Editor.Show(); // Editor is a WPF.Window

                }

            }

}
```

The problem: After desired window is opened, form with a treeview activates itself, making new window to go background.
How to make new window to remain active?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to let WPF finish the job of handling the current mouse click event(s) before you open the new Window. Let the new window be the *next* UI job by adding it to the current Dispatcher's queue like this:

```
(...)

//Editor.Show();
Action showAction = () => Editor.Show();
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(showAction);
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Thank you !

Comment: This works! Finally I arrived this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

in constructor of new form set

```
this.Focus();
```

Also, does your new form should be Modal window? if yes use `Editor.ShowDialog()` instead of `Editor.Show();` It will automatically solve issue with focus