# WPF Window loses focus after poping up in ListBoxItem's double click event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to show detailed information of some objects in a `ListBox` in new Windows, so I create and show a new Window in `ListBoxItem`'s `MouseDoubleClick` handler.

Here is an example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem MouseDoubleClick="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick" Content="Test" />
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            (new Window()).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

If I double click the "Test" item, a new Window pops up and then loses focus quickly. Why? How do I prevent the new from losing focus?

Also, I don't want to use `ShowDialog` method because I may need to open multiple Windows at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing UI operations in the middle of a mouse click event (or other UI event) often causes undesired behavior, like what you're seeing. See this answer for a workaround: [WPF TreeView restores its focus after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077266/1869660)